Why is this book dividing the black-scholes formula by the strike and not the spot?
In some lecture notes I'm reading, it says that a FX call option with premium paid in base currency is $$ \frac{\exp^{-r_qt} \left[FN(d_1) - KN(d_2) \right]}{K}$$
where $r_q$ is the quote rate.
Why does he divide by $K$? Should it not be the spot exchange rate $S$?

Sometimes the quote is expressed in percent of the amount of currency delivered at exercise.
